# Embedded id and "repeated column in mapping for entity..." exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem with JPA and Hibernate and I fail to solve it.

So, it is my applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.abt.fiifootballmanager">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
        expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>

<jdbc:embedded-database type="HSQL" id="dataSource" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    id="emf">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.abt.fiifootballmanager.entity" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceProvider">
        <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider" />
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" value="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

This is my Performance entity:

```
 package com.abt.fiifootballmanager.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name="PERFORMANCES")
@NamedQuery(name="Performance.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM Performance p")
public class Performance implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private PerformancePK id;

    @Column(name="RED_CARD")
    private BigDecimal redCard;

    @Column(name="YELLOW_CARD")
    private BigDecimal yellowCard;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="performance")
    private GoalkeepingPerformance goalkeepingPerformance;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="performance")
    private List<OutfieldPerformance> outfieldPerformances;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="MATCH_ID")
    private Match match;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PLAYER_ID")
    private Player player;
    ...getters & setters }
```

And this is my embedded id class:

```
@Embeddable
public class PerformancePK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="MATCH_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private long matchId;

    @Column(name="PLAYER_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private long playerId;
    ... //getters and setters
```

So, these are my classes. But when I want to run my application I get the next exceptions:
`1.Error creating bean with name 'emf' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory`

```
2. Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.abt.fiifootballmanager.entity.Performance column: MATCH_ID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

I think that the first exception it's caused by the second. So, why I get "Repeated column in mapping for entity?". It's a good idea to use an embedded id class?.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your two variables `match` and `player` in your `Performance` class are mapped to the same columns as `matchId` and `playerId` in the embedded ID. As the error says, they "should be mapped with insert="false" update="false"".

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="MATCH_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Match match;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="PLAYER_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Player player;
```

This essentially makes those fields readonly, so Hibernate knows only to change the `MATCH_ID` and `PLAYER_ID` columns if the values in the embedded ID are changed, but not if the values of `match` or `player` are changed.

Comment: Hibernate keeps saying about  Repeated column, even if add `insertable = false, updatable = false`

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem, and solved it by changing `@Embeddedable`/`@EmbeddedId` with `@IdClass`.

Your classes should look like (i omit some info):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PERFORMANCES")
@IdClass(PerformancePK.class)
public class Performance implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column(name="MATCH_ID")
  private long matchId;

  @Id
  @Column(name="PLAYER_ID")
  private long playerId;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="MATCH_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Match match;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="PLAYER_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Player player;

  ...//getters, setters
}


public class PerformancePK implements Serializable {

    private long matchId;

    private long playerId;

    ... //getters and setters

    // !!! MANDATORY: override hashCode() and equals() here
}
```

With this construction, your DB structure still the same.
More information about [@IdClass usage](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Id_Class).

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to do this using `@EmbeddedId`, but it may be easier to use the `@IdClass` annotation at the entity level. You can then set the `@Id` annotation on the `@ManyToOne` references directly:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PERFORMANCES")
@IdClass(PerformancePK.class)
@NamedQuery(name="Performance.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM Performance p")
public class Performance implements Serializable {

    static public class PerformancePK implements Serializable {
        private long match;
        private long player;

        public PerformancePK() {
        }

        public PerformancePK(long match, long player) {
            this.match = match;
            this.player = player;
        }

        // TODO: implements equals() and hashCode()
    }

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="MATCH_ID")
    private Match match;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PLAYER_ID")
    private Player player;

    ...
}
```

I have defined the PerformancePK class as an inner class because I find it convenient, but it doesn't have to be.