# using embedded id type twice in an entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

In my spring-boot project, I have a custom type for ID field of my entity. I can use the type with the help of `@Embeddable` and `@EmbeddedId`.

But when I want to add another field with the same type into a single entity, I get a column mapping exception as follows:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: 
com.example.demo.CarEntity column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

CarId class:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Embeddable
public class CarId implements Serializable {
    private String id;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

CarEntity class:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Entity
public class CarEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CarId id;

    private String name;

    private CarId anotherId;

}
```

Repository class:

```
@Repository
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<CarEntity, CarId> {
}
```

application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner runner(CarRepository repository) {
        return args -> {
            CarId carId = new CarId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            String carName = "a car";
            CarEntity carEntity = new CarEntity(carId, carName, carId);
            repository.save(carEntity);
            repository.findAll().forEach(carEntity1 -> {System.out.println(carEntity1.getId());});
        };
    }
}
```

How can I add multiple fields with the same type into the entry class?

Comment: I think the issue is that the embedded entity CarId has a "column" called ID, and the CarEntity also has a "column" called ID. Try to change the name of one of the id attributes to something else.

Comment: when I remove `anotherId`, it works although both CardEntity and CardId have the field `id`. Anyway, I renamed `id` in CardId to `cId`, the issue still stays.
`Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.example.demo.CarEntity column: cId (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")`

Comment: If you use an embeddable item twice this will happen, since the attribute cid will now be twice in the entity. You could eliminate this issue by asking the mapper to use the cid attribute as read-only (no insert, no update) in an explicit annotation. Maybe this issue will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29952386/embedded-id-and-repeated-column-in-mapping-for-entity-exception

Comment: thanks. if I mark the field read-only, then it does not complain. but it does not persist `anotherId` field either.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found is to override the field name on `anotherId` as follows:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Entity
public class CarEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CarId id;

    private String name;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverride(name="id", column = @Column(name = "anotherId"))
    private CarId anotherId;

}
```